# HTML/JQuery - Element Hiding by its ID

Tags: jquery, html

I need help hiding an HTML element with its ID example:

```
<p id="myelemnt">Hello all</p><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById.hide("myelemnt");</script>`
```

i tried that method and another method too example:

```
<p class="myelemnt">Hello all</p><script type="text/javascript">$(".myelemnt");</script>
```

but both of them aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First approach:

```
document.getElementById("myelemnt").style.display = "none";
```

Second approach (jQuery):

```
$(".myelemnt").hide();
```

Comment: This one worked 'document.getElementById("myelemnt").style.display = "none";' :D thanks so much

Comment: Better us `addClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery library and add the following code

```
$(function() {
    $("#myelemnt").hide();
});
```